# SQL Server: retrieve data that has been saved as question mark characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My problem is that my data in Persian language has been saved as question marks by mistake in choosing correct collation!

Now I need this data. Is there any way to retrieve this data and convert them to Persian language characters? Persian language characters must be saved as UTF like Arabic or Japanese.

Comment: It depends on how messed up your data is. Can you show what the hex dump loos like? (eg: `SELECT CAST(column AS VARBINARY(8))`)

Comment: If this is production data, did you test your insert statements before you pushed to production?

Answer (score 4):

If the data was saved as question marks because you did something like this:

```
INSERT dbo.table(col) SELECT 'Persian characters';
```

Instead of:

```
INSERT dbo.table(col) SELECT N'Persian characters';
-----------------------------^ this N is crucially important!
```

Then I'm afraid your data is gone. If, however, you are seeing question marks in the output, it may not be the case. Where are you seeing question marks?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to attempt to connect to this database, retrieve the data, and view the actual bytes that were stored.  If they are the correct bytes then you may be able to salvage the data.  If the bytes are all identical (a repeated string of `\x53` over and over if `\x53` represented the question mark) then the information is lost.

Comment: unfortunately question mark is in table:(

how can in view the actual bytes of this data?!

Comment: Cast(column as VarBinary(8)).  In Python you could do something like this:  `[hex(ord(c)) for c in 'string']`, but like the other answer says, if it was stored wrong, it's going to be gone.  :(

Comment: @Tamoochin how are you verifying that "question mark is in table"? Using what tool and what query?

Comment: I am using sql server 2005 managment studio, There is also persian language data with correct character. the current collation is arabic. but in time of data insert collation was latin by mistake:(