# Explicitly casting all string parameters to Unicode

Tags: sql-server

Is there a performance hit to prefixing all SP parameters with N' even when the parameter is not a unicode string?

I'm generating calls to a database dynamically in my .net code. Without actually checking each time I generate the code, I don't know which parameters are Unicode.

If the answer is yes (there is a performance hit), what's the simplest way to check whether a paramter is unicode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. If your column is Unicode you should always pass in a Unicode string.

However you shouldn't need to prefix strings from your .NET application with `N`. Are you not using parameterized statements?

Comment: The issue is that not all the parameters are Unicode. We can write code to detect that (or store the information in a meta data table). The question was whether it's worth it.
We have some scenarios where we don't use paramertized statements. We are in middle of changing it but for now we have to work with it.

Comment: If the parameter is Unicode, you should always pass Unicode. There can't possibly be any performance advantage to omitting the prefix when the string happens to not contain Unicode data...

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough. I apologize.
The code I'm talking about generates generic calls to many different procedures and functions in our database. The code is build using a meta data table where we store all available SPs and functions. Right now we don't have the information for each parameters indicating whether it's Unicode.
The question is: when building the string that contains the function call, do I prefix all parameters with N or do I take the hit and check each parameter whether it's Unicode.
I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Your question definitely makes it sound like you are talking about the string values, not the parameter data types. I would suggest that the difference in performance will be negligible and will not justify writing all the code to check for any non-Unicode parameters. You should consider some kind of code generation tool, though, to make that automatic. But in the meantime I would just treat all strings as Unicode. Then you don't run the risk of losing data like this guy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420830/sql-server-retrieve-data-that-has-been-saved-as-question-mark-characters